# Identify this Solitaire variant

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

I played a variant of Solitaire long ago (20+ years) but don't remember the name of it or the specific rules.

It was played with a single deck of cards, which you held in your hand face down. You drew 4 cards face up, keeping them in that same hand. Cards were removed / discarded through some matching criteria (which I don't remember), and if no cards could be removed, new cards were drawn one at a time. Each time a new card was drawn, the matching criteria were applied again. This repeated until the deck was empty. You won if you were left with no cards in your hand.

I remember it being quite difficult to win, but it was neat in that you didn't need a table or other flat surface. The game was played entirely in your hand(s).

Comment: This sounds like a game that I have played and the matching criteria was based on the top most 4 cards. If the suits of the 1st and 4th card matched you would discard the 2nd and 3rd card and check for a new match. If the value of the 1st and 4th card matched you would discard all 4 of the cards.

Comment: @Joe W, I take it you don't have a name for it? I used to play it too, but I don't know the name either